# How to call a function to display a snackBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a function to display a snackbar. When i call my function "ErrorPage" nothing is happening. I have no syntax error.

**Homepage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/src/screens/error.dart';

ErrorPage(message: "Can't reach the servers, \n Please check your internet connection!!!",);
//Nothing happening
```

**Error.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ErrorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;

  const ErrorPage({Key key, this.message = "There was an unknown error." }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   print("-------test------");
   return SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Class under which create a function and then call that function to trigger the snackbar

**Point to be noted:** you will need to pass `GlobalKey` to the snackbar if you want the snackbar to be accessible globally.

**`GlobalKey`** will enable you to show the snackbar on that particular screen.

```
//for creating a _scaffoldKey
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

//then add the reference of this key to your `scaffold` widget under `key` parameter
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  body: //your widgets
);
```

then create a new Class

```
Class GlobalValues{
    static showSnackbar(_scaffoldKey, String msg) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
         duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
         content: new Text(msg),
         backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800]));
    }
}
```

call the class from wherever you want like this

```
GlobalValues.showSnackbar(_scaffoldKey, "your message");
```

PS:  you can use `GlobalValues` class to store/ access variables, functions which should be accessible globally into your app.

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there this should get you the rest of the way.

```
//State class
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ErrorMessage(message: "There was an unknown error."),
    );
  }
}

class ErrorMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  ErrorMessage({this.message});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            content: Text(message),
          );
          //This is the line you missed
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```